# finite abelian group satisfying $x^2=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I looked but didn't see this question pop up.  Not homework as I am graduating on Thursday and took Abstract a year ago.  I'm taking the Praxis II and honing my skills.  I have good intuition about this problem but don't know if it is a sufficiently written proof.  This is from Herstein's Abstract Algebra 3rd Edition

If $G$ is a finite abelian group with elements $a_1, a_2,...,a_n$ are all its elements, show that $x=a_1a_2...a_n$ must satisfy $x^2=e.$

So since $G$ is abelian, $\forall{a_i},a_j\in{G}, a_ia_j=a_ja_i$, and since every $a_k$ has a unique inverse $a_k^{-1}$, eventually with enough operations, this thing kills itself. (I know, not great but how can I finish this so it finishes strong?).  And if $|G|$ is odd, that implies at least one $a_i$ is its own inverse, right?

Comment: If $|G|$ is odd, every nonidentity element pairs with its inverse, and $x$ itself is $e$. If $|G|$ is _even_, some of the $a_i$ are their own inverses, necessitating the squaring.

Comment: There could be more than one element being its own inverse. Just think of $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$: every element is its own inverse.

Comment: I don't know a rigorous way to say this, but consider the product $x^{-1} = a_n^{-1} a_{n-1}^{-1} \ldots a_2^{-1} a_1^{-1}$. Inverse is a bijection, so that product should also be $x$. (that's the part I can't rigor-ize). So if $x = x^{-1}$, $x^2 = e$.

Comment: got it, just at least one.

Comment: I see what you are all saying and was intuitively on the path,... it just seems "unmathy"

Comment: @HenrySwanson I would say that is rigourous. If you're nervous, you could always add that words in the group are determined by their letters and not by the order, because you can swap any adjacent letters by the commutativity relations, and these transpositions generate every permutation.

Comment: By hardmath's observation, your $x$ is the product of all order $2$ elements in the group ($e$ if there are no such elements). Non order $2$ elements cancel out. I just said that in case you had not noticed that being its own inverse meant having order $2$, except for $e$. But surely you had noticed that. It's just that $y$ has order $2$ is somehow more tractable than $y$ is its own inverse.

Comment: That is good, @julien, thanks.

Comment: This question has already appeared a couple of times on math.SE.

Comment: Oh, sorry @MartinBrandenburg i didn't see it (though i must admit my search was quick)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the elements of $G$ which are different from their inverses.  As you already noted in the question these cancel one another when you multiply all the elements together.

That leaves us the product of elements which equal their inverses, say $x = b_1 b_2 \ldots b_k$.  $G$ is of course abelian, so $x^2 = e$.

Answer (score 4):

Basically each of the elements $a_i$ in $G$ has an inverse $a_j$, with possibly $i=j$ but not necessarily. Abelianness allows us to pair them up, and cancel them nicely to get $e$. There is not much more than that. You can say "...there exists a bijection $f:[n]\to [n]$ such that $a_ia_{f(i)}=e$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$."

Answer (score 4):

You have the right idea - the point is that the commutativity allows you to shuffle the word $(a_1\dotsm a_n)^2$ until every element is next to its inverse, and then the whole thing collapses to $e$. There will be more formulaic ways of writing this, but they probably wouldn't be as clear.

Every group has an element that is its own inverse - the identity. I don't see anything in this proof that says there must be another one if the order of the group is odd, and indeed this isn't true - try the cyclic group of order $3$.